# AWS Device Farm with Selenium Wire Remote WebDriver

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-device-farm, seleniumwire

In my project, to be able to access a testing environment website I need to send a header request, otherwise I get a 404 error.
I'm running Selenium-wire using Jenkins on a server and running the browser on AWS Device Farm.
The thing is, some sites don't need the header and I can access normally, and for those the next config are working fine:

```
if browser_name == "chrome":
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        devicefarm_client = boto3.client("devicefarm", region_name="us-west-2")
        testgrid_url_response = devicefarm_client.create_test_grid_url(
            projectArn="arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:111122223333:testgrid-project:123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000",  # < exemple project's Amazon Resource Name (ARN)
            expiresInSeconds=300,
        )
        desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
        desired_capabilities["platform"] = "windows"
        driver = webdriver.Remote(
            testgrid_url_response["url"], desired_capabilities, options=options,
            seleniumwire_options={'auto_config': False, 'addr': '127.0.0.1'}
        )
        driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
        driver.implicitly_wait(30)

        driver.get("...")
```

For the site where I need to use the header I first start just adding the 'interceptor' function, and then I tried many other things:

```
elif browser_name == "chrome_1":
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server="IP-of-the-machine-running-Jenkins":8087')        
        devicefarm_client = boto3.client("devicefarm", region_name="us-west-2")
        testgrid_url_response = devicefarm_client.create_test_grid_url(
            projectArn="arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:111122223333:testgrid-project:123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000",  # < exemple project's Amazon Resource Name (ARN)
            expiresInSeconds=300,
        )
        desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
        desired_capabilities["platform"] = "windows"
        driver = webdriver.Remote(
            testgrid_url_response["url"], desired_capabilities, options=chrome_options, 
            seleniumwire_options={'auto_config': False, 'addr': '127.0.0.1', 'port': 8087} # < Here I've tried 0.0.0.0, IP of Jenkins machine, etc...
        )
        driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
        driver.implicitly_wait(30)

        def interceptor(request):
            request.headers['x-abc-abcdef'] = 'the-header-value'
        driver.request_interceptor = interceptor

        driver.get("...")
```

Plus, locally the 'interceptor' function with header work just fine in granting me access.

If anybody could throw some light here I'd be immensely grateful!

Thanks!

Comment: AWS Device Farm during doesn't pass headers from the remote web driver onto the browser. You may have to setup a proxy server (like [`BrowserMobProxy`](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy)) that does this if you really need the headers.